# Differences between @templating or @twig injection

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection, twig

Can someone explain what differences it makes to inject `@templating` or `@twig` in a service where we would like to render a twig template?

[The Symfony Documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html#core-symfony-and-third-party-bundle-services) shows `@templating` injection in its example, but I notice that it can create some problems, e.g. with the following design :

- `ServiceA` and `ServiceB`, have both `@templating` injected, and a single function `render()` returning html thanks to the `@templating` service
- `TwigExtA` and `TwigExtB`, are declared as `twig.extension` and injects respectively `ServiceA` and `ServiceB`, they implements functions `renderA()` and `renderB()`, calling the `render()` functions from the `ServiceA` or `ServiceB`

It create a circulare dependency graph : TwigExtA -> ServiceA -> @templating -> @twig -> TwigExtB -> ServiceB -> @templating

It seems that we cannot create 2 `twig.extension` services both having dependencies to `@templating`. **But it can be resolved injecting the `@twig` service instead.**

What is the reason for that?

Comment: To quickly answer `@twig` is `Twig_Environment` *(twig library)* whereas `@templating` is any `Templating` component service which implement `EngineInterface`. *(can be PhpEngine for example)*

Comment: So, my workaround only works because my project uses twig templating engine. Then I can inject `@twig` service in many Twig Extensions. But what if I'd like to use PhpEngine instead? I'd have to inject `@templating` service and the circular dependencies come back...

Comment: You should care about the circular reference even if you use Twig as templating service.

Comment: @AlterPHP could you please suggest another design? I don't know how to improve mine to not care about...